# GroupBy ID but keep multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| queue_id | email_id | user_id | customer_id |  send_date | campaign | approved | scheduled |
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
|    1     |    1     |    1    |      1      | 2018-10-30 |     1    |     1    |     1     |
|    2     |    1     |    2    |      1      | 2018-10-30 |     1    |     1    |     1     |
|    3     |    2     |    1    |      1      | 2018-11-02 |     1    |     1    |     1     |
|    4     |    2     |    2    |      1      | 2018-11-02 |     1    |     0    |     1     |
|    5     |    2     |    3    |      1      | 2018-11-02 |     1    |     1    |     1     |
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Where the `email_id`, `user_id`, and `customer_id` are all foreign keys.

What I need to do is return the `send_date`, `subject` (which is apart of the `email` table that the `email_id` references), and `name` (which is apart of the `business` table that the `user_id` references) but only for columns where the `approved` column is true. The idea is to ultimately display the data to a user in an HTML table where the table would look like the following (using the sample data provided):

```
+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| October 30th, 2018 | Subject for email_id "1" | View Approved |
| November 2nd, 2018 | Subject for email_id "2" | View Approved |
+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Whenever the user would click on the "View Approved" cell, then it would display all of the business names that approved that particular email.

I tried using the following query, but it is only returning one value in the `name` column:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(q.`send_date`, "%M %D, %Y") AS `date_visited`,
  e.`subject`,
  b.`name`
FROM
  `email_queue` AS q
INNER JOIN
  `email`    AS e ON q.`email_id`    = e.`email_id`
INNER JOIN
  `user`     AS u ON q.`user_id`     = u.`user_id`
INNER JOIN
  `business` AS b ON u.`business_id` = b.`business_id`
WHERE
  q.`approved` = true
GROUP BY
  e.`email_id`
ORDER BY
  q.`send_date` DESC
```

How can I structure my query to where it would return all of the business names in the `name` column instead of just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the unqiue business names in a Comma separated string, using [Group_Concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with Distinct clause.

Try:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.`name` SEPARATOR ',') AS name
```

instead of:

```
b.`name`
```

**Note:**

- You can avoid the usage of `Distinct` clause, if there would not be any duplicate `user_id` (for a specific `email_id`), thus ensuring that `b.name` is also unique.
- You can also use any separator, instead of comma. For eg: to use separator as pipe character `|`, you would write the query as:

  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.`name`SEPARATOR '|') AS name`

Comment: The comma separation didn't work for me because my data allowed for comma's in the business name, but what I did do is change the separator using the documentation from the URL that you provided. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @David what separator did you use ?

Comment: I wound up using `</li><li>` and then whenever I displayed the data I added the opening and closing tag to the beginning and end of the String.